# Converting KeyedVector to a tsv file

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I am trying to convert a KeyedVector word2vec object to a tsv file. Here is my code:

```
wv_embeddings = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True, limit=100000)
```

Would you loop through each of the embeddings and save them to a tsv file?

Answer (score 1):

The vocabulary is stored in `wv_embeddings.wv.vocab.keys()` and `wv_embeddings.wv.get_vector()` allows to get the vector corresponding to a word. The tsv can be written with the [csv standard module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('wv_embeddings.tsv', 'w') as tsvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
    words = wv_embeddings.wv.vocab.keys()
    for word in words:
        vector = wv_embeddings.wv.get_vector(word).tolist()
        row = [word] + vector
        writer.writerow(row)
```